# How can I do exponents (power) with vector quantities in Scala Squants?

Tags: scala, math

Using the Scala [Squants](http://www.squants.com/) library to perform cross product operations with vector quantities. Currently I'm working on the equation in Scala:

[image: Magnetic field equation]

Squants has a feature where I can perform cross-products of vector quantities, but the problem is that I can't do something like:

```
val vectorQuantity = DoubleVector(1.2, 1.2, 1.2)
math.pow(vectorQuantity, 3)
```

Is there a way to do this? I've also tried something like `vectorQuantity crossProduct vectorQuantity` but I'm just getting the compiler error `type mismatch; found: squants.Vector[Double]; required: Double`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import squants.DoubleVector

object Main extends App {

  println("Start :)")

  val vectorQuantity = DoubleVector(1.2, 1.2, 1.2)

  println(vectorQuantity)

  val product = vectorQuantity crossProduct DoubleVector(0.7, 2.3, 1)
  println(product)

  val result = DoubleVector(vectorQuantity.coordinates.map(c => math.pow(c, 3)):_*)
  println(result)

}
```

[sbt 0.13.7] [scala 2.11.5] [squants 0.4.2]

This compiles and works as expected.
Unfortunately API doesn't expose any kind of "map" functionality for DoubleVector which would be nice here. You can always ask a maintainer to add this.

I would expect this to work like that:

```
val pow3 = (id: Double) => math.pow(id, 3)
vectorQuantity.map(_.pow3)
```

Comment: Looks like it will do the trick, what I found weird here though is that you were able to perform a `crossProduct` of two `DoubleVector` classes. I was getting compiler errors.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Follow-up, the weirdness of my compiler error was caused by the fact that earlier in my equation, multiplying `DoubleVector` and a `Double` created a `Vector[Double]` class for unknown reasons. I'll probably map the coordinates similarly to your method to prevent it.

Comment: Hi, all.  Sorry for being late to the show on this (I am the primary maintainer).  The Vector feature in Squants is somewhat experimental at this point.  I am certainly open to merging any changes you need in this specific feature.  The DoubleVector * Double => Vector[Double] looks to certainly be bug in the API, which I will work on.  That map feature seems useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest SNAPSHOT build available today (0.6.1-SNAPSHOT) a few key issues outlined in this question are addressed:

1. The typing has been corrected so the crossProduct operation works as expected in the original question.  That is, DoubleVector is now used throughout the API, so no more conflicts with Vector[Double]
2. A `map` operation has been added to the Vector API which supports most any operation on the underlying Vector coordinates, including dimensional conversions (eg, Length => Area).  To perform the operation in the original questions, try the following code similar to kpbochenek's suggestion:

`val pow3 = (id: Double) => math.pow(id, 3)
    vectorQuantity.map[Double](pow3)`

Note the need to supply a type to the map method, as map may be used for other dimensional conversions as well.  For example

`vectorQuantity.map[Length](Meters(_))`